# Form view (for Inserting only) - contains drop down list

Tags: asp.net

I have a form view in ASP.NET with a text box and a drop down list.
I'm trying to populate the drop down list - from a separate table than the one I'm inserting data into.  For example - a list of states - with Value = CA; Text = California.

I have a LINQ statement that I've created, but I can't seem to populate the ddl.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First of all return a list from your table:

```
myEntities dc = new myEntities();
List<MyTable> lst = (from ro in dc.MyTable select ro).ToList();
```

Than, add an object into your list (or insert into a position).

```
lst.Insert(0, new MyTable(){TextField = "California", ValueField = "CA"});
drp.DataSource = lst;
drp.DataBind();
```

Comment: How do I get my text field and value field from dc.MyTable if there are multiple fields in the table.  I only need dc.ID and dc.Value so I modified your suggestion to do, "select new {ro.ID, ro.Value}"  But the drp.DataSource is producing an error.  And what does <MyObject> represent?

Comment: I removed myobject from my response. Can you post your code and the error ? I can have an idea like this and propose a solution. I need to see your html and c# codes.